# Doing customization for a cell but dont work

Tags: iphone

My purpose is to customize a cell for a row of my table view. So I am doing :

```
MyClass.m
    1 .- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{  
    3 .    NSLog(@"section %d:row %d",indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
    4 .    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"reusedCell";   
    5 .    DetailCell *cell    = (DetailCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    6 .    cell.backgroundColor    = [UIColor clearColor];
    7 .    // Customize the cell of each row from table
    8 .    **if ( cell == nil ) {
    9 .        cell    =   [[DetailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    10.    }**
    11.    return cell;
    12.}
```

my DetailCell class is

```
    1.- (DetailCell*)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{

    2.   if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]){
    3.  itemImg     =   [[UIImageView alloc]    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20 , 20, 50  , 70)];
    4   itemName    =   [[UILabel  alloc]       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0 , 100 , 50)];
    5.  itemDesp    =   [[UILabel  alloc]       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 40, 1000, 20)];
    6   itemSize    =   [[UILabel  alloc]       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 60, 100 , 20)];
    7   itemPrice   =   [[UILabel  alloc]       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 60, 100 , 20)]; }
    8.   [itemImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"large/dresses/02/71EU6.png"]] ;
    9.   itemName.text = @"Dresses";
    10.   itemDesp.text = @"Description";
    11.   itemSize.text = @"S";
    12.   itemPrice.text = @"$99";
    13.   itemSize.textColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

    14.   [self.contentView addSubview:itemImg];
    15.   [self.contentView addSubview:itemName];
    16.   [self.contentView addSubview:itemDesp];
    17.   [self.contentView addSubview:itemSize];
    18.   [self.contentView addSubview:itemPrice];
    19.        return self;
    20.    }
```

To display an img or text on the row of my table, I set img + text on UIImageView and Label within **DetailCell** ( line 8---> line 13 at DetailCell). 
However, when I went through some readings and I realized that people use a class such as DetailCell to create a frame + add properties for UIImageView + Label. Finally, they will display an image or text on cell within **myClass.m**. 
It is confusing me because  should we set img for UIImageView at **MyClass.m** or **DetailCell.m**. 
Please advice me about this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the cell is not nil, It won't work.  You would typically configure cells based on section or row.  What cells are you trying to customize?  Say you wanted the first cell to be styled like this and the other ones not...

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0: 
        cell = [[DetailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        break;
    default:
        /*
         * Configure the rest of the cells... 
         *
         * Use case 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. as needed.
         * You can then use default to set the default configuration
         */
         break;
 }
```

You could try a method like that instead.  Also be sure that you don't have this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

This is the default and will limit the amount of cells you can have. If you have multiple sections, use a switch statement similar to the one used in the previous example.

Comment: yeah, I have a problem like my post at [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696295/issue-when-trying-to-create-my-own-cell_italic_**code**`code`. I dont know why my cell is not nil at first time. so is your switch in method cellForRowAtIndexPath, rite ? why we should not have numberOfRowsInSection = 1. I think it is not a problem because you can have 1 section with multiple rows(or cells ).