# issue when trying to create my own cell

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm working on customizing my cell like below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"reusedCell";    
 DetailCell *cell = (DetailCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
// Customize the cell of each row from table
 if ( cell == nil ) {
     NSLog(@" MY CELL IS NIL");
     cell = [[DetailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
else
     NSLog(@" MY CELL IS NOT NIL");
}
```

By debugging, I know that line 4-5 are not reached at all

```
MY CELL IS NOT NIL
```

Therefore, I cant create my own cell. According to apple documentation

> Typically, the first thing the data source should do is send dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: to the table view, passing in a reuse-identifier string. If the table view does not return a reusable cell object, the data source creates one, assigning the object a reuse identifier in the final parameter of initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:

Therefore, in my situation, the table view does return a reusable cell object... Where it comes from then...
Have any one experienced this issue before. Please help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first time a list is shown, cell will always be nil.  Then as cells are scrolled off the ends, they are recycled through the reusable list.  So sometimes when you debug, the cell is nil, and sometimes you get a recycled cell.  Also, if you use the same identifier (i.e. @"reusedCell") on multiple lists (which you shouldn't), a cell from another list may get recycled into your list.  That's why you should keep the cell identifiers unique.

Comment: I agreed that at the first time list is shown, cell is nil. I  have unique identifier named reusedCell and  1 list to play around...Still dont know why my cell is not nil...

Comment: First time list is shown, cell is nil.  Agreed so far.  The list is painted with cells you've allocated as DetailCells.  Next time, you go to paint list, it sees there are previously used DetailCells, and gives you one of those yourself.  Just treat it like you'd treat a new cell, it's just a recycled cell.  When you call cellForRowAtIndexPath, and you've already allocated some cells, you can't tell if there will still be a used cell still sitting in memory that it will give you first.  Also note that since that cell had to be created in lines 4-5, you know it's one of your cells.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create new cells each time when the user scrolls the table means, you need to override the reuseIdentifier property of the UITableViewCell in your custom cell class.

```
- (NSString *) reuseIdentifier
{
    return @"";
}
```

This will let you to create new cell. But, check out the memory usage. Bcoz you are creating new cell each time when the user scrolls the table.

Comment: This is not a good idea.  Apple has specified the correct method, if someone uses the above without awareness of the memory considerations, it will cause them problems.  Best to stick to Apple's method.